# How to add an image to asciidoc book cover page?

Tags: pdf-generation, asciidoc

I would like to create a pdf book using asciidoc. The title page should include the title, subtitle and an image. So far I could not find any documentation on how to achive this.

Intuivly I would do something like

```
My book title
=============
:author: myself
:toc:
image:images/titelimage.png[width=400]
```

but this just adds `image:images/titelimage.png[width=400]` as a subtitle. What I would like to have is something like

```
My book title
<titleimage>
subtitle
```

Is there a way to do this in ascciidoc? If not, what do I need to do to get this?

Answer (score 16):

If you're using [asciidoctor-pdf](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-pdf) you can define an attribute for the logo. It will place the image *above* the document title.

```
:title-logo-image: images/titelimage.png
```

See an [example pdf](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-pdf/raw/master/examples/chronicles-example.pdf) here and the [raw adoc](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-pdf/master/examples/chronicles-example.adoc).

Comment: I think it's now called 'title-logo-image', see the [https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-pdf/tree/master/examples](examples) directory (new link)

Answer (score 7):

If anyone is still looking for this answer, this is the correct way to do it (using asciidoctor-pdf):

```
= Book title
Authors
:front-cover-image: image::./images/title_page.png[]
```

This gives you the image by itself as the first page followed by a page that shows the title, authors, revision etc.

If you want the image on the same page as the title and author, you need to use `:title-logo-image:` instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a PDF using the docbook 4.x output you should:

Generate a docinfo file with an image for the front page. This is an XML file looking like the following example. It is discussed at http://www.methods.co.nz/asciidoc/userguide.html#X87

Example:

```
<mediaobject>
  <imageobject>
    <imagedata align="center" depth="400" fileref="../images/tiger.png" />
  </imageobject>
</mediaobject>
<subtitle>Subtitle of this book</subtitle>
```

Then, customize your DocBook stylesheets to include the media element for the title page (by default the stylesheets do not include this). http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/TitlePagePrint.html

DocBook 5 includes a cover element in its stylesheets.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
= The Book's Title
:author: First Last
:email: first.last@company.com
:toc:
:toc-placement: preamble
:doctype: book

image:./images/title_page.jpg[]
```

Produces:

```
My book title
first.last@company.com - first.last@company.com
Image
Table of Contents
...
```

Comment: I will try that out probably next week and will let you know if it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add a empty line between the toc and the images: instruction. That's how asciidoc kinda separates blocs.

Comment: Actually, I don't use :toc: anymore, just title. I generate a book, which automatically adds a toc. Putting the image just after the title with a free line inbetween does not do the job.