# add cover page with asciidoctor

Tags: pdf-generation, asciidoctor

Does anyone know a way, how to add text to the cover page. More precisely, I need a table on the front page of my generated pdf. I am using asciidoctor with asciidoctor-pdf to generate a pdf out of my asciidoc file. I hope someone can help me out here.

I already know, how to add an cover background image, but that does not help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19354075/how-to-add-an-image-to-asciidoc-book-cover-page

Answer (score 2):

`front-cover-image` (separately generated) offers full control of the page.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/chloerei/asciidoctor-book-template/master/book-sample.adoc

Alternatively, you could customize the converter ...